# Kotlin Contracts: assert instance on reified type parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin, assertj, kotlin-reified-type-parameters, kotlin-contracts

I'm trying to write an assert function that checks if a given object is of a type `T`:

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <reified T> assertIsInstance(value: Any?) {
    contract {
        returns() implies (value is T)
    }

    Assertions.assertThat(value).isInstanceOf(T::class.java)
}
```

The function uses AssertJ to do the concrete assertion but I'm willing to let the compiler know that after its execution, the `value` is of type `T` so that a smartcast is possible. It seems like this does not work because:

`Error in contract description: references to type parameters are forbidden in contracts`

Is there another way to achieve this behavior? What's the issue here? Will this eventually be possible?

(Using Kotlin v1.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point there were some (deeply technical) concerns regarding support of such constructions in an IDE, but it's possible that this limitation will be relaxed in the future.

Comment: thanks for the response. Any alternative approach to implement such a contract?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 unfortunately, there's no way to work around it at the moment. You can track status this feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28298

Answer (score 4):

This has been bugging me for a couple hours, especially since this is possible:

```
val x: Any = "string"
require(x is String)
val len = x.length
```

The compiler is clearly able to understand these, so this is likely a limitation of the contracts themselves.

I've spent a while now trying to come up with some workarounds. For reference:

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <reified T> assertIsInstance(value: Any?) {
    contract {
        returns() implies T::class.isInstance(value))
    }
    if(value !is T){
        throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect type");
    }
}
```

"Unsupported construct"

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <reified T> assertIsInstance(value: Any?, condition: Boolean = value is T) {
    contract {
        returns() implies condition
    }
    if(!condition)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect type");
}
```

Compiles, but doesn't enable smart cast. The original motivation behind that one was placing a boolean in front of the contract, but contracts need to be the first part of a function, which made that impossible. You might as well remove the contract; it's useless in this case.

This was my last try:

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun assertIsInstance(value: Any?, cls: KClass<out Any>) {
    contract {
        returns() implies (cls.isInstance(value))
    }
    if(!cls.isInstance(value))
        throw IllegalArgumentException("");
}
```

Another "unsupported construct".

Somehow I ended up with this:

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun assertIsInstance(value: Any?) {
    contract {
        returns() implies (value.hashCode() == 0)
    }
    if(value.hashCode() != 0)
        throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

But this gives a new error: `only references to parameters are allowed in contract description`.

## TL;DR:

It doesn't look like you can. Sneaking it in like I did in the second example doesn't trigger smart cast, and the rest don't work due to various compiler errors.

At least for now, there doesn't appear to be a way. You could of course open an issue in the Kotlin repo and ask for something like this, but for now, it doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that passes the my unit tests on Kotlin 1.8.20:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
@Suppress("UnusedPrivateMember")
public inline fun <K : KClass<V>, reified V> Any.checkIsInstance(kClass: K, lazyMessage: () -> Any): V {
    contract {
        returns() implies (this@checkIsInstance is V)
    }

    if (this !is V) {
        val message = lazyMessage()
        throw IllegalStateException(message.toString())
    } else {
        return this
    }
}
```

Edit: This can simplify to a version very similar to that in the original post, suggesting that the problem is now fixed in Kotlin:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
public inline infix fun <reified V> Any?.checkIsInstance(lazyMessage: () -> Any): V {
    contract {
        returns() implies (this@checkIsInstance is V)
    }

    if (this !is V) {
        val message = lazyMessage()
        throw IllegalStateException(message.toString())
    } else {
        return this
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed works for me.
```
fun t() {
    val s: String = ("" as Any).checkIsInstance<String> {""}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the *as* operator do this?

```
fun main() {
    val x: Any = "string"
    x as String
    val len = x.length
    println(len)
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/uFCsGWEZm